# Azure web app connection to azure sql fails?

Tags: azure, azure-webapps, azure-sql

1. I Created a Web App,
2. Ive setup a Azure sql server with a private endpoint
3. Created a Azure SQL database on the above sql server
4. Created an endpoint for SQL server database and added firewall rule
   to allow azure services through, also added vnet where private
   endpoint is on to the firewall

However when i try to tcpping to the azure sql database from the console of the web app,  i keep getting connection failed?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ok it seems you need to append :1433 at the end of the tcpping otherwise it wont work! Go to your web app console and type the below in substitute the "adbsql01" with your sqlservername
eg

- tcpping adbsql01.database.windows.net:1433